# About the tangent space to a corner point of a manifold with corners.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces

So it is well known that if $y$ is a boundary point for a $k$-manifold $M$ in $\Bbb R^n$ then a vector $\vec v$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is tangent to $M$ at $y$ if and only if there exist a parametrized curve $\gamma$ defined in a open neighborhood of $0$ that carries the right or left part of this neighborhood into $M$ such that
$$
y=\gamma (0)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\vec v=\gamma'(0)
$$

So I ask if this result is still true for corner points of a $k$-Manifold of class $C^r$ for any $r\ge 1$ with corners that is defined to be a $k$-manifold having some local patch defined in an open set of $\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}$ for any $h\le k$.

To follow some reference about well know definitions and elementary results about manifolds: I put here
them to show the formalism I use about manifolds; moereover I point out that theese reference (from the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres) are for manifolds with boudary but reading them it is not hard to see that the definition and results can be easily (is this false?) extended to a manifolds with corners. So if you like click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5vL4.png) to see it, otherwise (provided you like it!) see my proof attempt.

**MY PROOF ATTEMPT**

So let be $\gamma$ a parametrized curve defined in a open neighborhood of $0$ that carries the right (or left) part of this neighborhood into $M$ so that $\gamma(0)$ is a corner point for $M$ and we shall prove that that its derivative $\gamma'$ at $\gamma (0)$ is a tangent vector to $M$. So let be $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ a coordinate patch about $\gamma(0)$ and thus putting
$$
y=\alpha(x):=\gamma(0)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\vec v:=\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)|_{t=0}\,\,\,\text{and thus}\,\,\,\vec u:=D\alpha^{-1}(y)\cdot\vec v
$$
we observe that
$$
\alpha_*(x;\vec u)=(y;D\alpha(x)\cdot\vec u)=(y;D\alpha(x)\cdot D\alpha^{-1}(y)\cdot\vec v)=(y;D(\alpha\circ\alpha^-1)(y)\cdot\vec v)=(y;\vec v)
$$
and so we conclude that $\vec v$ is a tangent vector to $M$ at $y$.

So let be $y$ a corner point for a $k$-manifold $M$ in $\Bbb R^n$ and we shall prove there exist a parametrized curve having the properties described above. So is $y$ is a corner point for $M$ coordinate patch $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ defined in a set $U$ that is open in $\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}$ for any $h\le k$   but not in $\Bbb R^k$ so that
$$
y=\alpha(x)
$$
for some $x\in\text{bd}\Big(\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}\Big)$. Now if $(y,\vec v)$ is a tangent vector to $M$ at $y$ then there exist $\vec u\in\Bbb R^k$ such that $\vec v=D\alpha(x)\cdot\vec u$ and moreover since $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}$ there exist an open cube $C(x,r)$ centred at $x$ and of radius $r>0$ such that.
$$
C(x;r)\cap \Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}\subseteq U
$$
and so first we suppose that $h=1$. Well in this case observing that $x+t\vec u\in C(x,r)$ iff $x_i+tu_i\in(x_i-r,x_i+r)$ and so iff $tu_i\in(-r,r)$ let be
$$
\epsilon:=\min\Big\{\frac{r}{|u_i|}:i=1,...,k\Big\}
$$
so that
$$
x+t\vec u\in C(x;r)\cap\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}
$$
for any $t\in[0,\epsilon)$ or $t\in (-\epsilon,0]$ if $u_k\ge 0$ or $u_k\le 0$ respectively. So observing that
$$
D\alpha(x+t\vec u)|_{t=0}=D\alpha(x+0\cdot\vec u)\cdot\vec u=\vec v
$$
we conclude the result holds for $h=1$. So unfortunately if $h>1$ then
$$
x+t\vec u\notin C(x;r)\cap\Bbb R^{k-h}\times[0,+\infty)^{h}
$$
because it could be that $x_{i_1}=x_{i_2}=0$ for $i_1,i_2=1,...,k$ and $u_{i_1}<0$ and $u_{i_2}>0$ so I do not be able to implement the above arguments. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Hint: The claim you are trying to prove is simply false, already for $k=2$ and $M$  equal the positive quadrant in ${\mathbb R}^2$. (Assuming that tangent space to a manifold with corners  is defined so that it is a vector space.) I suggest you draw picture and try to find an example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay, so the statement is false. Anyway is true that the tangent space at a **corner** point $p$ defined as $$D\alpha(x)\cdot\vec v$$ where $x=\alpha^{-1}(p)$ and $\vec v\in\Bbb R^k$ is independet from the choice of the local patch $\alpha$, right?

Comment: I do not understand your definition but a better one would be as the set of equivalence classes of smooth curves $\alpha: [0,1)\to M$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$, where the equivalence relation is the usual one. This space is not a vector space but has an extra structure making it isomorphic to $R^{k-h}\times [0,\infty)^h$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Which is the usual equivalence relation? Sorry, but I do not know it because (**it seems**) I define the tangent space in a little different way: if you click in the link that I posted in the question above you can see it at the end of the linked page. Anyway (provided I do not tire you) could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144451/is-a-cylindroid-a-manifold-with-corners), please?

Comment: The usual definition is that two smooth curves $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)=p$ are equivalent if for each chart $\phi$ at $p$, $(\phi\circ \alpha)'(0)=(\phi\circ \beta)'(0)$.