# find a base topology

Tags: general-topology

**Exercise:** Let $(X,t_1)$, $(Y,t_2)$ be topological spaces where $ X=\{1,2,3\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$

$t_1=\{\emptyset, X,\{1\},\{2,3\}  \}$,
$t_2=\{ \emptyset , Y, \{1\}     \} $

find a base of the product topology $X\times Y$

**my solution:**
we know $t_1$ is a base for $X$ and $t_2$ a base of $Y$ so we just need to find the product $t_1 \times t_2$

$t_1 \times t_2= \{\emptyset, X\times Y, \{ X\times\{1\}  \},\{\{1\}\times Y\}, \{(1,1)\},\{\{2,3\}\times Y \},  \{\{2,3\}\times \{1\} \}                   \}$

**Is the set $t_1 \times t_2$ correct ?**

Comment: Shorta answer: No. Too many braces at some places e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base for $\mathcal{T}_1$ is $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and for $\mathcal{T}_2$ it's $\{\{1\},Y\}$. (we don't need $\emptyset$ in a base).

So the generated product base is $\{\{(1,1)\}, \{(1,1), (1,2)\}, \{(2,1), (3,1)\}, \{(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2)\}\}$, so $2 \times 2 = 4$ subsets.

Write  out a set like $\{2,3\} \times\{1\}$ as $\{(2,1), (3,1)\}$ etc. Show it as set of pairs.

Comment: Thank you a lot !I was really confused

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144451/is-a-cylindroid-a-manifold-with-corners), please? It is some days I am trying to solve this problem: initially I thought it  was a pure analytical probelm but pheraps today I discovered that it could have actually a fairly topologial solution.